# Can not Install pycharm-debug-py3k.egg in virtualenv for python 3.6.4

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

My Environment: Windows7 64bit, Python 3.6.4 64bit, PyCharm 5.0.4.

and I want to install pycharm-debug-py3k.egg in Virtualenv, so I use these command:

> G:\Python\Project\VideoHelper>workon VideoHelper_PY3.6
>   (VideoHelper_PY3.6) G:\Python\Project\VideoHelper>easy_install.exe
>   easy_install.exe G:\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg

but it show some error like these:

> G:\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg Processing pycharm-debug-py3k.egg removing
>   'c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg'
>   (and everything under it) creating
>   c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg
>   Extracting pycharm-debug-py3k.egg to
>   c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages   File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_SimpleXMLRPCServer.py",
>   line 272
>       except Fault, fault:
>                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_SocketServer.py",
>   line 339
>       print '-'*40
>               ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print '-'*40)?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_inspect.py",
>   line 293
>       raise TypeError, 'arg is a built-in module'
>                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_pkgutil_old.py",
>   line 543
>       except IOError, msg:
>                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_uuid_old.py",
>   line 151
>       if not 0 <= time_low < 1<<32L:
>                                   ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg_pydev_imps_pydev_xmlrpclib.py",
>   line 294
>       True, False = True, False
>       ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to keyword
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\pydev_ipython\inputhookglut.py",
>   line 98
>       print '\nKeyboardInterrupt'
>                                 ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int '\nKeyboardInterrupt')?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\pydevd_attach_to_process_check.py",
>   line 2
>       print add_code_to_python_process.run_python_code(3736, "print(20)", connect_debugger_tracing=False)
>                                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\pydevd_attach_to_process\winappdbg\plugins\do_example.py",
>   line 37
>       print "This is an example command."
>                                         ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int "This is an
>   example command.")?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\pydevd_attach_to_process\winappdbg\plugins\do_exchain.py",
>   line 40
>       print "Exception handlers for thread %d" % thread.get_tid()
>                                              ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\pydevd_attach_to_process\winappdbg\plugins\do_exploitable.py",
>   line 46
>       print "-" * 79
>               ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int "-" * 79)?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\stubs_get_tips.py",
>   line 280
>       print temp % dict(method_name=entry[0], args=entry[2] or '(self)', doc=doc)
>                ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\tests_python_debugger_case_qthread2.py",
>   line 19
>       print "Increasing"
>                        ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "Increasing")?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\tests_python_debugger_case_qthread3.py",
>   line 19
>       print "Increasing"
>                        ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "Increasing")?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\fixes\fix_unicode.py",
>   line 32
>       val = ur'\'.join([
>                  ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\main.py",
>   line 93
>       except os.error, err:
>                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\conv.py",
>   line 63
>       except IOError, err:
>                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\driver.py",
>   line 126
>       except IOError, e:
>                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\grammar.py",
>   line 116
>       print "s2n"
>                 ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "s2n")?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\literals.py",
>   line 56
>       print i, c, s, e
>             ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print i, c, s, e)?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\pgen.py",
>   line 206
>       print "Dump of NFA for", name
>                             ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "Dump of NFA for", name)?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\pep8\lib2to3\lib2to3\pgen2\tokenize.py",
>   line 157
>       print "%d,%d-%d,%d:\t%s\t%s" % \
>                                  ^ SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(int "%d,%d-%d,%d:\t%s\t%s" % )?
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\wrapped_for_pydev\ctypes__init__.py",
>   line 27
>       raise Exception, ("Version number mismatch", **version**, _ctypes_version)
>                      ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\wrapped_for_pydev\ctypes\macholib\dyld.py",
>   line 136
>       raise ValueError, "dylib %s could not be found" % (name,)
>                       ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> File
>   "c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg\third_party\wrapped_for_pydev\ctypes\util.py",
>   line 59
>       except OSError, e:
>                     ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>
> pycharm debug is already the active version in easy-install.pth
>
> Installed
>   c:\users\gotop\envs\videohelper_py3.6\lib\site-packages\pycharm-debug-py3k.egg
>   Processing dependencies for pycharm===debug

Comment: You don't really need to install it, you can simply add it to `PYTHONPATH`, e.g. `import sys; sys.path.append('path_to_debug_egg_parent_folder')`.

Comment: @Pavel Karateev, you method solve my problem. You should make it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks.